# Notify UI of changes in entity framework items

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am working on a sports application, where teams play in groups against each other and the group matches are automatically generated when a team is added to or removed from a group. Like in the soccer WC for instance. To store the teams and matches I use a database and EF. For the UI I use WPF and MVVM.

Now I am looking for a good code design that notifies the UI when a team is added to (or removed from) a group and new matches are automatically created (or deleted) about the changes in the EF data model.

I currently use observable collections and copies of the EF entities to accomplish the UI notifications, but this raises a lot of issues regarding transactions, because in in case of rollbacks I need to rollback the changes in these collections as well.

More generally speaking, how do I make the business layer provide observable collections and objects to the UI for the entities in the data layer that fire notifications when the data layer changes are committed?

Any suggenstions on how to do it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need to rely on EF events? Why can't you just introduce some custom event that will be raised when the team is added successfully?

Comment: @AlexRiabov agree with you. I think it must be the best practice for that kind of thing. Traditional  .Net events will do the job. At least it is a business logic so why delegate that to EF which is, for sure, your data layer?

Comment: So you mean that the business layer simply raises an event that the data has changed. In turn the UI viewmodels sync their data with the data layer. That seems to be a much easier approach than mine. But that also means that the data layer would need to cache the data to avoid additional roundtrips to the database. I will give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer myself according to Alex Riabov's comment. The business layer simply raises an event that the data has changed. In turn the UI viewmodels sync their data with the data layer. But that also means that the data layer would need to cache the data to avoid additional roundtrips to the database.

Comment: Hm. I still wonder if it would not be much better if the business layer would notify the UI about what exactly has changed, instead of just raising an event that says something has changed and leave it up to the UI to figure out what has changed.